# Using my nuget package generates lots of DLLs

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

I am new to using NuGet packages, and need some help...

I have created one NuGet package. When using it in a VS project, after I build the project, a lot of DLLs are created in my output folder. I would have expected a single dll corresponding to my nuget package... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd expect any DLLs from dependencies to be there too. Those aren't being *generated* - they're being copied. But they wouldn't end up in your NuGet package. Have a look at the nupkg file after building the package, and I suspect you'll just find the DLL for your code.

Comment: To have a look at my NuGet package, I renamed it as zip, and opened it (correct?). Then, I could only found a single DLL in it, this DLL has the name of my NuGet package. This looks correct to me, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, or download the NuGet Package Explorer.

Comment: All sounds as expected to me, yes.

Comment: And when I install the package in a brand new WinForm app, and compile it, the bin\release folder gets populated with almost 100 DLLs...

Comment: Yes as mentioned by @JonSkeet the "100 DLLs" are coming from your package's dependencies. If you would like to reduce it and this package is owned by you, try to reduce the number of nuget package as much as possible

Comment: Thanks you both for your answers. I found where the probleme comes from.
My NuGet package is a class library that targets .NET standard 2.0
The WinForm app in which I installed the NuGet package targets the .NET Framework 6.1.
When compiling, the missing dlls in the .NET Framework 6.1 were added to my output folder...
When targetting the .NET Framework 4.7.2, I get the expected result :-)
Have a good day